# Analysis of Newton's Method

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods, newton-raphson

I want to use Newton's method to find the roots of 
$$ 2x^3 − 9x^2 + 12x + 15$$
for $x=3$, $x<-3$, and $x>3$. I see that if $x=3$, the Newton iterates do not converge. How do I handle the cases when $x>3$ and $x<3$. I don't see an obvious behavior in the iterates after going through a few steps with guesses in $x<3$ or $x>3$. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Newton's method is only guaranteed to converge to a solution (that satisfies $f'(x) \neq 0$) if you start 'close enough'.

In this case the polynomial $p$ has exactly one real root, and since
$p(-1) = -18, p(0) = 5$, we see that it lies in $(-1,0)$.

Try starting at $-{1 \over 2}$ for example.

Comment: Thanks. I know where the loot lies; the case I mentioned is for $\textit{all}$ $x<3$, not just in $(-1,0)$.

Comment: As said, there is only one real root. Differentiate your expression and locate its turning points.

Comment: @Moz: A little analysis shows that Newton's method will converge starting from any initial point in $(-\infty,0]$. I'm not sure how you conclude that behaviour for all $x<3$?

Comment: I suspect Newton's method will converge for many more values, but it will be a little chaotic initially.

Comment: If you plot the function $n(x) = x - { f(x) \over f'(x)}$ it will give you some sense of what is happening.